# No sound unless root in Debian Buster

Tags: debian, audio

I've just done a dist upgrade on my Debian SID computer, and the sound disappeared.

I can play an audio file in root, but not as a normal user.
I've checked that I'm in the "audio" group.
I've checked to see if anything is muted by running *alsamixer*, but all line is up and running.

Here are the Audio output I have on the computer:

```
$ lspci  | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

I have an unplugged HDMI output (the NVIDIA controller). My audio headers are plugged on my Intel controller.
I can see this driver when I run *alsamixer*, but only see the HDMI output from my graphics card in the *pavucontrol* output devices.

[image]

When listing my audio sinks, I only get one null device:

```
$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 2
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY FLAT_VOLUME DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 56362 /  86% / -3,93 dB,   front-right: 55706 /  85% / -4,23 dB
            balance -0,01
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 5,63 ms
    max request: 6 KiB
    max rewind: 6 KiB
    monitor source: 2
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stéréo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 2000,00 ms
    module: 20
    properties:
        device.description = "Sortie factice"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

I don't really understand deeply how the sound system works in Debian, but I think I understand that my normal user does not have the right to access the Intel chip. From here, I'm stuck and can't really find out what to do...

### EDIT:

I managed to get back the sound by disabling auto-mute in alsamixer. This settings has been somehow change during the system update.

But after a reboot, the problem came back, but the auto-mute was still off.

Thanks to dirkt answer, I think I have found the source of this issue:
When running *aplay -L* as normal user and root user, I noticed some differences:

```
$ aplay -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Default Audio Device
$ sudo aplay -L 
default:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Default Audio Device
```

It seems that the default card is not the same when running as simple user.
I could have some sound when selecting *sysdefault* instead of *default* card as normal user.

```
$ aplay -D sysdefault sound.wav
```

But now, I'm a bit stuck. I think I've pinpoint the source of the issue, but cannot find out how to solve it...

Comment: Restore from backup and file a bug with the distro maintainer.

Comment: I had the same symptoms after upgrading to buster and it appeared timidity was holding alsa (that's basically what I understand). Uninstalling timidity restored the sound.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this issue for me by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge timidity
```

Please make sure this will only remove **timidity** and **timidity-daemon**. As far as I understand the daemon grabs some resources on startup and prevents the other services from finding the sound cards. I think timidity has something to do with MIDI files so make sure you do not need this when uninstalling the packages and make sure that you know what you uninstall.

Hope this resolves the issue for some users. You might want to reinstall timidity in the future when the above mentioned issues are resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Brief overview of sound: The sound hardware is managed by kernel drivers (formerly a part of ALSA), ALSA provides libraries to access the kernel drivers (this is what you see with alsamixer), and Pulseaudio runs on top of ALSA. One reason for that is that without extra effort, ALSA devices can only be used by a single program, while Pulseaudio allows multiple programs to use the hardware by providing a transport layer.

No sink with Pulseaudio means Pulseaudio failed to grab the ALSA device(s), possibly because (1) permissions are wrong, (2) something else is already using them, (3) something totally different went wrong.

So the first step is to stop Pulseaudio, then use `aplay -L` to see your ALSA devices, and try `aplay -D ... audio_file.wav` to see if you can access the device directly. Depending on the result of that the next step is either to look what is blocking the device (something else has started earlier and is using it), or to find out why Pulseaudio isn't using the ALSA devices (e.g. load [module-alsa-card](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index6h3) directly with `pacmd`, look at the error message/log entries). How to stop Pulseaudio depends on how you started it, possibly with systemd, possibly via your Desktop system login.

Inspecting the command line of running processes with `ps axu` etc. may give hints about the points mentioned above, and will also make sure Pulseaudio has been stopped properly, and is not restarting itself.

Comment: This helped me find out the source of the problem. Thanks. I've edited my question to reflect advances in this issue.

Comment: Spot on. There is indeed an issue with Timidity that gets triggered when upgrading to Buster. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=901148

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved: after the upgrade, I don't know why, the output was in automute. I just had to change it in alsamixer.

Sometimes, digging deep is not needed.

Comment: Since you said you checked if anything was muted, this was hard to guess from your question...

Comment: I understand. But while checking this I missed the auto-mute option that I did not know about.

Answer (score 1):

As it works with "root" user, maybe is it just a problem of group membership and your login name is not (yet) member of the group "audio".

On my debian buster "ben" user is member of group "audio" :

```
ben@debian:~$ cat /etc/group | grep "ben"
tty:x:5:ben
dialout:x:20:ben
cdrom:x:24:ben
floppy:x:25:ben
sudo:x:27:ben
audio:x:29:pulse,ben
dip:x:30:ben
video:x:44:ben
plugdev:x:46:ben
netdev:x:109:ben
bluetooth:x:113:ben
scanner:x:117:saned,ben
ben:x:1000:
docker:x:130:ben
wireshark:x:131:ben
ben@debian:~$
```

You could also use the command to make sure (check in /etc/group)

```
useradd -G audio <your username>
```

And finally, re-open a session in order for the change to be effective !

Comment: This question was five and a half years old and concerns software that will hit its final EOL of even its extended long term support in a few months, and *already had a perfectly good and accepted answer*. We appreciate your enthusiasm and willingness to share your knowledge, but please refrain from necromancy like this unless the question is 1) about something that could still be an issue and 2) doesn't have an accepted answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem comes from the fact you've got PulseAudio AND a NVidia GPU w/ the blob.

The solution consists in preventing PulseAudio from starting by inserting garbage in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf (just a single letter at the end of the file). Then you will only be able to set the volue through AlsaMixer but at least sound will be back.

I've raised ticket #918522 about this issue. Feel free to contribute.