# How can I select sysdefault as the global audio device?

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, audio-volume

I'm having [this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/452079/129690) (except without the Nvidea GPU, I think) after upgrading from Stretch to Buster; I can't play sounds through `default`, but I can play sounds through `sysdefault`.

However, the Volume Control widget only lets me select two devices, neither of which is `sysdefault`:

[image: Only "default" and "HDA Intel PCH" are listed.]

How can I select `sysdefault`, in order to play audio through the speakers again?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `alsamixer`, followed by F6, followed by typing `sysdefault`. (I can't convert the `asciinema` to GIF, so this'll have to do for now.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of the XY problem. [As per srgbnd's Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1346784/541767), this issue is caused by Timidity stealing the device on boot – a more permanent "quick and dirty" solution is to uninstall `timidity-daemon`, since the `pulseaudio` solution only seems to work once.

Debian bug [#901148](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=901148) is the relevant one.

```
wizzwizz4@myLaptop:~$ systemctl stop timidity
Please type your password to authenticate as root...
wizzwizz4@myLaptop:~$ pulseaudio -k
```